# How do I get the actual data from Hadoop cluster (after map reducing) using the python API Pydoop?

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm using a python API (pydoop) to map reduce the HDFS file, but i want to know how i can retrieve the original data using pydoop or any other technique using python.

Comment: You want to read the file stored in HDFS using pydoop?

Comment: HI Suraj,I want to read the original content of the file stored in HDFS that is in map reduced format (mr_output).

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce applications (run either with Pydoop or via the standard Hadoop Java API) write their output in a user-specified directory, creating one file for each reduce task (or one per map task in the special case of map-only jobs): `part-r-00000`, `part-r-00001`, etc. You can look for these files and read their content with Pydoop's HDFS API:

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs

MR_OUT_DIR = "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/foo/mr_output"

data = []
for path in hdfs.ls(MR_OUT_DIR):
    if hdfs.path.basename(path).startswith("part-"):
        with hdfs.open(path) as f:
            data.append(f.read())
```

Comment: HI Simleao, Thanks a lot! May i know why we are mentioning "part-" in startswith("part-") ?

Comment: I have added some introductory text which explains -- among other things -- the `part-` bit